# What is the correct sentence

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, comparatives

Which one is correct?

> Two thirds of the crop **is** destroyed.

or:

> Two thirds of the crop **are** destroyed.

Comment: ***Half the sheep are dead*** (half of the *number* of multiple sheep). Somewhat less likely, ***Half the sheep is dead*** (one sheep, half of whose body is necrotised?).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - But (countable) sheep are different, surely? Is it "(a portion of the crop equal to 2/3) **is**" or "Two (portions equal to 1/3) **are**"? I think I'd go for the latter.

Comment: Arguably this should have beenn migrated to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). But see [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=half+the+crop+is%2Chalf+the+crop+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) showing that it's virtually always ***Half the crop is destroyed***, not ***...are destroyed***. Don't be distracted by the fact that it's ***two** thirds* - it's still ***A fraction***.

Comment: @KateBunting: Plural makes more sense with, say, *Two-thirds of the **herd** are infected*. But for nearly all possible referents, there's at least the *possibility* of using the "less-favoured plurailty". My tongue-in-cheek sheep example was supposed to show that there are at least *some* contexts where one plurailty would be *extremely* unusual! :)

Comment: As I understand it, Brits happily switch between ***couple is*** and ***couple are*** depending on whether we're thinking of the couple "collectively" or as two people, and we do the same with a ***herd*** (not so much with a ***crop***, though). But maybe Americans are more wedded to ***two-thirds is***, same as with couples.